# Null Pointer Exception while trying to run Java multi threaded server

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception, serversocket

I'm trying to write a java message switch application by using a multi-threaded server and two clients. However I'm stuck at one point as error occurs when I try to run my programmes. Here are my codes for the server:

```
public class EchoServer extends Thread {

private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket connection1;
private static Socket connection2;
private BufferedReader input;
private PrintWriter output;
final static int portNumber = 4434;

public EchoServer(Socket in,Socket out) throws IOException{

    connection1 = serverSocket.accept();

    connection2 = serverSocket.accept();

    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in.getInputStream()));
    output = new PrintWriter(out.getOutputStream(),true);
}

public void run()
{
    String inputLine;

        while((inputLine=input.readLine())!=null){
            if(inputLine.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
                break;
            System.out.println("received:" + inputLine);
            output.println(inputLine);
        }
            System.out.println("received quit,exiting");
    }

public static void main(String args[]){


            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);

        System.out.println("listening on port:"+ portNumber);

        EchoServer echoserver1 = new EchoServer(connection1,connection2);
        EchoServer echoserver2 = new EchoServer(connection2,connection1);
        echoserver1.start();
        echoserver2.start();

    }
}
```

I also wrote two classes for client. When I run the server and then the first client, they work as expected. However when I try to run the second client, a NullPointerException is thrown, regarding to the following two lines:

```
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in.getInputStream()));
        EchoServer echoserver1 = new EchoServer(connection1,connection2);
```

I know it's a rather long piece of codes to look at, but I'm really stuck as I can't see the problem here. The earlier single threaded version of server I wrote worked without error, so I know there's something to do about the multithreaded. Any help and advice is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`connection1` and `connection2` are never initialized in your `main` method, hence you get a `NullPointerException` when you call `in.getInputStream()` in your constructor.

Not completely sure what you're trying to achieve, but looks like you might want to move these two lines

```
connection1 = serverSocket.accept();
connection2 = serverSocket.accept();
```

to your `main` method.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked right away after I moved those lines as you suggest. I'm trying to write two message switching clients which can be used to send message to each other based on a multi-threaded server. It's not finished yet but your answer really helped a lot. Thanks again!